# Mysql Trigger use inserted value as column name for update After Insert

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have 2 tables: One for storing **order_products** and another one for keeping **inventory levels for multiple stores**

---

The **order_products table** keeps the ID for the store in the **store_id** column.

```
product_id | quantity | store_id
```

The **inventories table** has a **product_id** column and subsequent columns for keeping inventory levels for each store. The name of each of those columns is the store_id.

```
product_id | 1 | 2 | 3 |....
```

I'm trying to set up an **Update AfterInsert Trigger** for updating inventory levels of the **inventories table** upon succesful insert in the order_products table.

The following is the query that needs to be performed:

```
UPDATE inventories

SET store_id = (store_id - quantity.NEW)

WHERE product_id = product_id.NEW
```

How can I use the inserted **store_id** value from the **order_products** table as the store_id column value in the update query?

I thought of using prepared statements but I believe they are not allowed for triggers.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll be better off rethinking the design of inventory table.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might not be so good as well, what would you suggest @mustaccio

Comment: Typically such tables would have as columns `product_id`, `store_id`, and `quantity` (possibly `last_updated` timestamp if you need this information).

Comment: @mustaccio Wouldnt that cause a lot of repetition since I would have to keep the same product_id for each of the stores? Then again I'm no expert in DB design.

Comment: Define "a lot". In your current design you potentially have even more repetition, as you store something (even if it is a NULL indicator) for stores that do not have a particular product in stock. No matter how you spin it, you must store three things for each combination of (store, product, quantity), but your current design lacks flexibility -- if you add or remove a store you must change the entire table structure, while  with the  alternative desing you simple add or delete records. -- And you can also create a trigger that you want.